# How to sort a list of maps in scala?

Tags: scala

I query data from multiple tables, and each has a customized key.  I put the data from these tables into a list of maps and want to sort it by the `id` value.

What I end up with is:

```
var g = groups.map(i => Map("id" -> i._1, "job" -> i._2))
var p = people.map(i => Map("id" -> i._1, "job" -> i._2))
var party = g ++ p
```

Which gives me:

```
var party = List(
    Map(id -> 1, job -> Group1),
    Map(id -> 2, job -> Group2),
    Map(id -> 2>1, job -> Person1Group2)
    Map(id -> 1>1, job -> Person1Group1),
    Map(id -> 1>2, job -> Person2Group1)
)
```

But I want to sort by `id` so that I have it in an order so that i can populate a tree structure:

```
var party = List(
    Map(id -> 1, job -> Group1),
    Map(id -> 1>1, job -> Person1Group1),
    Map(id -> 1>2, job -> Person2Group1),
    Map(id -> 2, job -> Group2),
    Map(id -> 2>1, job -> Person1Group2)
)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor refactoring of the associations in each `Map` by using case classes may simplify the subsequent coding; consider

```
case class Item(id: String, job: String)
```

and so by using (immutable) values,

```
val g = groups.map(i => Item(i._1, i._2)
val p = people.map(i => Item(i._1, i._2)
```

Then

```
(g ++ p).sortBy(_.id)
```

brings a list of items sorted by id.

If you wish to group jobs by id, consider

```
(g ++ p).groupBy(_.id)
```

which delivers a `Map` from ids onto lists of items with common id. From this `Map` you can use `mapValues` to extract the actual jobs.

Comment: Thanks elm, that worked. But my example was simplified, and I actually need more than 22 different fields in my Item. I get an error saying that the Item cannot have more than 22 fields. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok thanks. is it possible to have a map (Mon: String, Tue: String) inside the Item?

Comment: Also, instead of the Item I actually need a JSONObject. How would I convert each of these after having sorted them?

Answer (score 2):

as hinted above party.sortBy(_("id")) should do it